# Updating row in table causing the row to be duplicate

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

I am facing a strange problem when I try to update a certain row in my table.
I am using the Connection class from java.sql library. Following is my table script:

```sql
CREATE TABLE `crd_web_request` (
    `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `order_id` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
    `trn_notes` varchar(200) DEFAULT NULL,
    `trn_date` date NOT NULL,
    `amount` double(20,3) DEFAULT '0.000',
    `other_amount` double(20,3) DEFAULT '0.000',
    `card_fees` double(20,3) DEFAULT '0.000',
    `shipping_fees` double(20,3) DEFAULT '0.000',
    `sys_trtype_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
    `crd_agent_mast_id` int(11) DEFAULT '0',
    `sys_phase_id` int(11) DEFAULT '0',
    `sys_user_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
    `cust_aname` varchar(250) DEFAULT NULL,
    `cust_ename` varchar(250) DEFAULT NULL,
    `sys_nationality_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
    `passport_id` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
    `sys_doc_type_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
    `cust_doc_id` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
    `cust_email` varchar(250) DEFAULT NULL,
    `cust_address` varchar(250) DEFAULT NULL,
    `cust_tel` varchar(30) DEFAULT NULL,
    `card_holder_name` varchar(400) DEFAULT NULL,
    `status` int(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    `cardType_ID` int(20) DEFAULT NULL,
    `sys_org` int(2) DEFAULT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`,`order_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=237 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

and following is my java code to update the table:

```java
Statement stmt = null;
String query = "UPDATE smcpp16.crd_web_request SET status = 1 WHERE order_id = '" + orderId + "'";

try {
    stmt = conn.createStatement();
    System.out.println(query);
    stmt.execute(query);

    stmt.close();
    conn.close();

} catch (SQLException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

I can it figure out why this is happening. Every time when executing the update statement, the table inserts a new record with the same values of the updated row. Can you please help?

Comment: How do you see that its duplicate?

Comment: @lapkritinis I am not sure I got what you mean. But, the duplicate not appearing here (in my question). The duplicate happening in the data of the table

Answer (score 0):

I removed the closing of the connection from this code and the duplication is not happening any more.
I just removed: 
            conn.close();

Answer (score 0):

It is a practice to close the connection in the finally block, something like this :

```
try{
     // update data
    }
catch{
      //catch exception
}
finally{
      //close connection
    conn.close();
}
```

Let me know if this helps.